# conversion from string "g" to type "Double" is not valid vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm facing with the `conversion from string "g" to type "Double" is not valid vb.net` error every time I'm debugging. I couldn't find the solution so far.

I need to submit this project by tomorrow, but I can't get rid of this problem.

Below is my code and database table:

```
Private Sub Load_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    Try

        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Stud_FirstName, Stud_LastName, Stud_Age, Stud_ICNumber, Stud_DateOfBirth, Stud_BirthPlace, Stud_PhoneNumber, Stud_Email, Parents_FirstName, Parents_LastName, Parents_Age, Parents_ICNumber, Parents_Address, Parents_Salary, Parents_PhoneNumber, Parents_Relation FROM Student Info Query where Stud_ICNumber= " & Me.txtIC.Tag
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                Me.txtIC.Tag = dr("Stud_ICNumber")
                Me.txtFname.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_FirstName")), dr("Stud_FirstName"), ""))
                Me.txtLName.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_LastName")), dr("Stud_LastName"), ""))
                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_DateOfBirth")) Then
                    Me.txtDateB.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
                    Me.txtDateB.Value = dr("Stud_DateOfBirth")
                End If
                Me.txtAge.Text = CInt(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_Age")), dr("Stud_Age"), ""))
                Me.txtBirthPlace.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_BirthPlace")), dr("Stud_BirthPlace"), ""))
                Me.txtPhone.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_PhoneNumber")), dr("Stud_PhoneNumber"), ""))
                Me.txtEmail.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Stud_Email")), dr("Stud_Email"), ""))
                Me.txtFNameP.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_FirstName")), dr("Parents_FirstName"), ""))
                Me.txtLNameP.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_LastName")), dr("Parents_LastName"), ""))
                Me.txtAgeP.Text = CInt(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_Age")), dr("Parents_Age"), ""))
                Me.txtICP.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_ICNumber")), dr("Parents_ICNumber"), ""))
                Me.txtAddP.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_Address")), dr("Parents_Address"), ""))
                Me.txtSalaryP.Text = CDec(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_Salary")), dr("Parents_Salary"), ""))
                Me.txtPhoneP.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_PhoneNumber")), dr("Parents_PhoneNumber"), ""))
                Me.txtRelationP.Text = CStr(IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Parents_Relation")), dr("Parents_Relation"), ""))
            End While
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: break and check which line the error occurs.and there will be some type conversion problems as you are trying to assign a string value to a variable with double datatype.

Comment: you can check too which field has value "g" in your database, to know in which part the conversion fails

Comment: I'm not sure you've correctly isolated *where* the problem is yet. I can't see anything in the code you've posted that would seem to involve a double. You need to debug your code and/or try creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if you set all database values to the textboxes, 
you don't need to convert to own types(CInt, CDec), just convert all values to string

Comment: Does your currency nationalization have a `"g"` in it? If so, your Currency column (`Parents_Salary`) may be the issue. Though it would be nice to know what line the error occurs on.